# cURL request does not display any content

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to recover the content of a page with PHP cURL. It works well on other websites, but on this website it does not work and I don't why.

Here is my code :

```php
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://ratings.fide.com/top.phtml');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

echo $result;
```

Comment: Does `curl_error` show anything?

Comment: Yes I just learned that it is necessary to execute curl_error after curl_exec, I did it before and it did not give anything. So the result is "Unknown SSL protocol", I executed the request simply by removing the https and it works, thank you!